# CiviCRM MailChimp API Limitations

Tags: extension, mailchimp

I'm running into an issue that I'm unsure is code-related or workflow-related, so I'm cross-posting on the CiviCRM StackExchange as well. I'm able to configure everything to talk well with MailChimp, but when I do a dry run Pull sync from MailChimp to a fresh CiviCRM group, I'm only seeing 10 Contacts syncing over from lists I know have between 13 and 700 Contacts. I've combed through the issue discussions but don't see any tracking of this particular issue.

As far as I can tell, I'm not seeing any errors Is there an API issue I'm running into? I've tried a configuration both with a mature and a fresh MailChimp account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First check would be to ensure the master group to list includes all the contacts that could be in the sub groups. This is where most people trip up.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I started a new List, added 13 Contacts to the list, and set it to sync with a CiviCRM Group. When I did a Dry Run of the Pull sync bulk operation, the API appears to have only returned 10 Contacts in the MailChimp list, rather than 13. Since this is a fresh / test account, I actually don't have any sub groups at this testing stage, but I will absolutely scan my production account to make sure that's not the limitation.

Comment: I did a quick GET test using the command line and was running into the same 10-Contact limit -- I followed this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654697/how-do-i-get-more-than-10-entries-from-users-or-interests-using-mailchimp-api-3 and added a count variable to the API URL in the command line and it returned the appropriate number of Contacts. Reviewing the source now.

Comment: ok - looks like a change as a result of moving to the v3 APIs. Please do feedback how you get on

Comment: Success. Minor modification of the /Sync.php file to add the appropriate API v.3.0 count call manually to the list membership URL on line 126. I'm not too familiar with PHP, but it looks like the 'count' => $batch_size, on line 127 isn't reporting properly to the API, or the API 3.0 change has updated how the count call works (appending it to the API call URL instead of the method used in 2.0.)

Comment: I'll be doing more thorough "pull" and "push" sync testing tomorrow in a live environment so will report any errors or challenges with this temporary fix in my situation. Earlier tests didn't suggest a similar challenge with "push" sync so with luck that part of the equation is still functioning as intended.

Comment: Great - any chance you could create a patch and submit it back to the repository?

Comment: I'm working today on how that process relates to the batch processing already in the module -- my "pull" task has been error-ing out at around 10,000 Contacts (with debug mode active, I have to tell it to "skip" the current task after 15-20m and it returns about 10k Contacts.) I will gladly submit a patch for review once I work out this challenge today!